# print if link for MySQL connection or database have an error

Tags: php, sql

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
if (!$link) {
  die ("MySQL Connection error");
}


mysql_select_db($db_name, $link) or die ("Wrong MySQL Database");
```

i tried to code some lines if $link or $db_name not ok echo some text

something like this

```
if (!$link || !$db_name) {
  echo 'Some Text Here';
}
```

but it didn't work

please how i can do that ?

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you to choose. If you care to learn, here is good [PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_select_db` is a boolean function, so.

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);

if(!$link && !$db) {
  echo "nothing works";
}
```

[**But please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.